# TFS 2015 - How to capture results of a manual Test case for use in second test

Tags: tfs, alm, mtm

We have a the following test work flow:

The user runs through the steps of a manual test case. 
The test passes, buy we need to capture the output of the test steps (a claim # is generate) and save it with the test results.
We need that number for auditing as well as future tests where we have to run a new test based on that claim number.
To make it more interesting the tests are manual tests against a mainframe application. The user has 2 monitors, monitor on left is TFS manual steps the other is running a mainframe terminal emulator.
Can I create a step in the test case that asks the user for input so that we can save the results of the test case?

Any thoughts

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of a claim #? As you want to input something in a step, how about add a comment?

Comment: I will get a screenshot and post it.